# Fibonacci Numbers - Add odd numbers only - Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, sum, fibonacci

So I am trying to develop a formula that will sum all odd Fibonacci numbers up to and including a given number.

For example:

- Given number is 4. Then result should be 5 (Odd Fibonacci numbers being 1, 1, 3).

Currently this is my code:

```
function sumFibs(num) {
  var sum = 0;
  for(i=0,j=1,k=0; k<=num;i=j,j=x,k++) {
    x = i + j;
    if (x%2 !== 0) {
      sum +=x;
      if (sum >= sum) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
sumFibs(4);
```

Clearly the code doesn't work. If I remove the (if sum >= sum) break statement it creates an infinite loop.  I have taken the for loop from another post here where a formula was given to create a Fibonacci sequence, but I am having difficulty with what to do after that number is generated, how do I add it. My way of trying to do this is by checking if the modulus is not 0 (which indicates it is an odd number).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `if (sum >= sum) {` will *always* evaluate true, what was that line trying to do?

Comment: oh wait, should that have been `sum >= num` - now *that* would make more sense

Comment: Removing that `if` along with the `break` [does not create](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesThorpe/0tjh71wp/) an infinite loop

Comment: change `for(i=0,j=1,k=0;` to `for(var i=0,j=1,k=0;` otherwise it will reach out and modify global values for `i,j,k`. (Also `var x = i + j;`)

Comment: Use the normal method to compute the Fibonacci series upto your desired number. And then just add all the odd numbers up. Might take up some space if the desired number is huge.

Comment: This is a case where function composition makes the code much more expressive. `fib(4).filter((val) => val % 2).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)` should really be all that's needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

your code is a bit confusing with the variables names and declaration (always try to declare using var).
here's a function that gets what you need

```
function sumFibs(num) {
  var fib0 = 0;
  var fib1 = 1;
  var fib = 1;
  var sum = fib0;
  while ( fib <= num){
    if (fib % 2) {
        sum += fib1;
    }
    fib = fib0 + fib1;
    fib1 += fib0;
    fib0 = fib1 - fib0;
  }

  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The code is somewhat confused... (what is `k` for?, the number of elements is irrelevant in the problem definition, also the problem talks about summing fibonacci numbers up to a certain value, not up to when the sum gets past a certain value).

A solution could be

```
var prev_fib = 0, cur_fib = 1;
var sum = 0;
while(cur_fib <= num) {
    if (cur_fib % 2 !== 0) {
        sum += cur_fib;
    }

    // Move on to next Fibonacci number
    var next_fib = cur_fib + prev_fib;
    prev_fib = cur_fib;
    cur_fib = next_fib;
}
```

Choosing longer variable names can help

Answer (score 2):

Smallest way to do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/PuneetChawla/gzr68ccv/

```
function sum()
{
    var a = 1;
    var b = 0;
    var c = 0;   
    var d = 4;       
    var temp = 1;

    while(c<d-1)
    {
        c = a+b;
        if(c%2 !=0){
        temp = temp+c;
        }
        b=a;
        a=c;
    }
    alert(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've got a solution close to some others listed, but i find mine to be a bit more readable, so here it is:

```
function sumOddFibs(num) {
  var sum = 2;

  var prev = 1;
  var curr = 1;
  var next = 2;

  while (next <= num) {
    prev = curr;
    curr = next;
    next = prev + curr;

    if (curr % 2 !== 0) {
      sum += curr;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution.

```
function sumFibs(num) {

  var a = 0, b = 1, f = 1, sum = 0;
  var arr = [0, 1];

  while (f <= num) {
    if (f % 2 == 1)
      sum += f;
    arr.push(f);
    f = a + b;
    a = b; 
    b = f;       
  }

  console.log(arr);
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked Neong's response. It probably isn't as elegant as others but it works. Best

```
function sumFibs(num) {

   var a = 0, b = 1, f = 1, sum = 0;
   var arr = [0];

   while (f <= num) {
     arr.push(f);
     f = a + b;
     a = b; 
     b = f;       
     }

   var OddOnly = arr.filter(function(value, index, array){
       return value%2 == 1;
   });

   var sumArr = oddOnly.reduce(function(a,b){
       return(a+b);
   })};

   return sumArr;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sumFibs(num) {

  if(num === 1)
    return 1;

  var fib = [];
  fib[0] =1;
  fib[1]=1;
  for(var i=2; i<=num;i++){
    fib[i]=fib[i-2]+fib[i-1];
  }

  fib = fib.filter(function(val){
    return (val % 2 !== 0) && (val<=num);
  });

  fib = fib.reduce(function(a,b){
    return a+b;
  });

  return fib;
}

sumFibs(4);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function sumOddFibonacciNumbers(num) {
    //initialize an array with the first two numbers

      let fib= [1,1]

    //for-loop to push numbers according to the Fibonacci sequence 
    // up to and including the num

      for (let i = 0; i <= num; i++){

        if (fib[i]+fib[i+1] <= num ) {
            fib.push(fib[i] + fib[i+1])
        }
    }
   
    // filter the odd numbers and then reduce to get the sum
    return fib.filter(a => a % 2 !==0).reduce((a,b) => a+b)
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.